# Duplo Activity table to Lego System Table

Tags: compatibility, duplo

We purchased a table with Duplo baseplates on top (activity table) for my son when he was 1 year old. He's now turning six and we would like to convert the Duplo top to the regular LEGO System top. is there a baseplate that has Duplo studs on the bottom (so it sticks and essentially covers the Duplo spaces) and regular LEGO System studs on the top (so that the table can be used with the regular LEGO System pieces. It seems like a shame to chuck the table.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question, no there is no such plate with DUPLO tubes on the bottom and LEGO studs on top. HOWEVER regular LEGO and DUPLO are completely compatible - as long as the regular LEGO bricks are at least 2x2 studs. Just cover the DUPLO table with regular LEGO bricks and you are done...(c;

You could actually use regular LEGO plates too, however the connection won't be as secure as with regular LEGO bricks as plates are much thinner so won't go all the way down to cover the LEGO studs. But they do fit, and their benefit is that they cover a much larger area so you would need less.

Here is an article and some visual examples of how LEGO and DUPLO fits together very nicely: http://thebrickblogger.com/2010/12/lego-duplo/

Comment: you are awesome!!!! I'm going to try that now...now just have to scrounge enough flat duplo plates 2x4 to fill the top :) thanks! The reason for this is that that top has solid rounds and not the originall duplo round to connect to the system so your idea worked when I placed the flat duplo on top first and then use the regular system bricks :) so I am figuring if I get a could of duplo base plates and put them on top first, the table would be good to go I think :)

Comment: Marisabel, that sounds like a plan! You can get some quite large DUPLO plates on BrickLink so you don't have to work with a lot of smaller ones (4x8, 6x12, 8x8 and 8x16). It is just something to consider investing in in the future. You can find them here:  http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=2&pg=1&catString=487&catType=P

Comment: You can use the large bricks such as the [12x24](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30072) to build the surface of the table. This will give it better stability and should bind correctly to the underlying duplo, plus it saves time in assembly.

Comment: Some additional notes: Marisabel is right that the duplo table has solid studs (not compatible with normal legos) when every other duplo brick has hollow studs, so you need a layer of duplo and then a layer of standard. I just ordered bricks to convert a duplo table to standard legos, it needed 12 standard 8x16 plates (tall enough to fit the duplo studs) and 12 duplo 4x8 plates.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly this is problematic.

Duplo baseplates generally have flat-topped studs, these studs are incompatible with lego. Furthermore thin lego plates don't have enough depth to take up a duplo stud.

So you are looking at at least two layers for the conversion each at least one full leog brick thic. The lower layer would be duplo plates (one lego brick high) followed by a layer of regular lego bricks. You can get oversized lego bricks which would probablly help in making it less likely for your conversion layers to come apart.